# Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection in RStudio when Running Dimple Chart

Tags: r, rstudio, rcharts, dimple.js

Yesterday I created a simple app in RStudio which if given a range of years would render an animated chart of the population for each year in the range. It worked well when I went to bed. Woke up, restart the machine, run the same code and now I get the error

```
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") :
  cannot open file 'C:\Users\Tee\Desktop\Sandbox\dimple/config.yml': No such file or directory
```

When I put a breakpoint and step through my code, I see that the error is thrown on the penultimate line (71) `return(d1)`. Am confused as I do not see how this one line is looking at a directory which does not concern it (the `\dimple` directory contains a different Shiny App) and looking for a file I have no idea about and never heard of (`config.yml`). The Entire code is below:

```
library(rCharts)
library(plyr)


getData <- function(startyr,endyear) {
  df <- read.csv("C:\\path_to_csv\\data2.csv")
  df <- subset(df,(year >= startyr & year <= endyear))
  return(df)
}


# DimpleJS pyramid

myPyramid <- function(startyear, endyear, colors=NULL) {
  dat <- getData(startyear, endyear)
  dat$n <- ifelse(dat$sex == 'MAL', -1 * dat$n, 1 * dat$n)
  dat$gencode <- ifelse(dat$sex == 'MAL', 1, 2)

  d1 <- dPlot(
    x = "n", 
    y = "agegrp", 
    groups = "sex", 
    data = dat, 
    type = 'bar')


  d1$yAxis(type = "addCategoryAxis", orderRule = "ord")
  d1$xAxis(type = "addMeasureAxis")
  d1$legend( x = 60, y = 10, width = 700, height = 20, horizontalAlign = "right")

  if (!is.null(colors)){
    d1$colorAxis(
      type = "addColorAxis", 
      colorSeries = "gencode", 
      palette = colors
    )
  }
  if (endyear - startyear >= 1) {
    d1$set(storyboard = "year")
    max_x <- round_any(max(dat$n), 1000, f = ceiling)
    min_x <- round_any(min(dat$n), 1000, f = floor)
    d1$xAxis(overrideMax = max_x, overrideMin = min_x)
  }

  if (max(dat$n >= 1000000)) {
    d1$setTemplate( afterScript = 
                      "
                    <script>
                    x._getFormat = function () {
                    return function(d) {
                    return d3.format(',.1f')(Math.abs(d) / 1000000) + 'm';
                    };
                    };
                    myChart.draw()
                    </script>
                    ")
  } else {
    d1$setTemplate( afterScript = 
                      "
                    <script>
                    x._getFormat = function () {
                    return function(d) {
                    return d3.format(',.0f')(Math.abs(d) / 1000) + 'k';
                    };
                    };
                    myChart.draw()
                    </script>
                    ")
  }

  return(d1)
}
```

And the data used can be found here https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kilimba/data/master/data2.csv . I am not sure what could have changed between yesterday and today, apart from me falling asleep, any help greatly appreciated in solving this?

Cheers,
Tumaini

Comment: Check the error. It's trying to find `config.yml` in the `Sandbox\dimple` folder of your desktop. I'll bet you had a different current directory the last time you run this script.

Comment: but I have never created a `config.yml` file at any point, and why is it even looking for this file anyway, am not asking it to? How to resolve? And what is the root cause of the error so I know how to avoid it next time? Thanks